# String-variables having many lines in js

Tags: javascript

**EDIT** OK, I've realised there is already an answer answering this question with **NO**: [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Thanks for all escaping/concatenating answers, but it is not what I needed.
**END EDIT**

In Python it is possible to define string variables having many lines by the notation

```
"""
many
many lines
"""
```

Is there something like this in JavaScript?

Comment: var string = 'many'+
+'many lines'+
+'lines';

Comment: You can add a `\\` at the end of each line, but no..

Comment: @Kitler: I always check if an answer is suggested while I write the question. I yes, I skip writing and use the answer.

Comment: @Mateutek Your luck, that comments can't be downvoted:-). You probably meant:  ' \t many  \t\t\n'+ +'\n\n \n\n \tmany lines\t\n'+ +'\t \t \tlines\n\t\n';

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Exactly :) Some IDE do this way out of the box

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use it like this:

```js
var str = 'many\n' +
          'many lines';
```

Answer (score -1):

Although such a thing does not exist in Javascript there is a way around it. Instead of the occasional `""" """`, you can add a `\` at the end of each line. That in turn will create a "Multi-line string". Here is an example:

```
var myString = "This is \
                my multi \
                line string";
```

---

**EDIT**

I thought I should also point this out. Another way of accomplishing this is to concatenate together the strings, like so:

```
var myString = "This is" +
               "my multi" +
               "line string";
```